# Power in series LCR circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, resonance

> In a series LCR circuit R=200 ohm and the voltage and the frequency of the main supply is 220 V and 50 Hz respectively. On taking out the capacitance from the circuit the current lags behind the voltage by 30°. On taking out the inductor from the circuit the current leads the voltage by 30°. How much power is dissipated in the LCR circuit ?

In this question as we can see, it is a resonance condition and hence power can be calculated by (220)²/200.

But if we consider any other phase change where unequal phase difference comes when we remove inductor and capacitor, then how to find power dissipated?

Comment: How did you know you have a resonance condition? Did you determine the values of the capacitor and inductor?

Comment: As you can see after remove either inductor or a capacitor same phase lag is coming. Hence there reactance would be same. And it can happen only in the condition of resonance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instantaneous power of a circuit is always $P(t) = I(t) V(t)$, and so you can calculate the power by integrating this over one period of the driving. For the specific case of a sinusoidal voltage a simpler procedure is available, which will reproduce the result of this calculation. Sum up the impedances of all the circuit elements (which in general will be complex numbers), take its modulus, and then the power is $V_0^2 / |Z|$, where $V_0$ is the amplitude of the voltage.

Comment: The instantaneous power equation you give is the total instantaneous power  which includes reactive (non dissipated) power and resistive (dissipated) power